# Parse XML with tags not grouped under one tag, but really should be

Tags: php, xml

I happen to be unfortunate enough to be working with an api that has images on the same XML tag level as the other tags and have the subscripts i.e 1,2,3,4 as part of the tag name of the image. Total images of each vehicle will vary in count.

```
<Vehicle>
 <TITLE>Some car name i dont need</TITLE>
 <DESCRIPTION>Some description i also dont need</DESCRIPTION>
 <IMAGE_URL1>{imagelinkhere i want}</IMAGE_URL1>
 <IMAGE_URL2>{imagelinkhere i want}</IMAGE_URL2>
 <IMAGE_URL3>{imagelinkhere i want}</IMAGE_URL3>
 <IMAGE_URL4>{imagelinkhere i want}</IMAGE_URL4>
</Vehicle>
```

I am using PHP's method **simplexml_load_file(xml_url)** to parse the entire xml into an object array.

My question: Is there a way to get these images using the same method which is also efficient and clean?

EDIT:
I have just refined the xml to show that there are other tags i dont need there and already handling.

Comment: How do you define clean and efficient? Can you show us your existing code how you used the object array? Maybe then, we can see what we do to improve it.

Comment: please check the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xml = '<Vehicle>
         <DESCRIPTION/>
         <IMAGE_URL1>{imagelinkhere}</IMAGE_URL1>
         <IMAGE_URL2>{imagelinkhere}</IMAGE_URL2>
         <IMAGE_URL3>{imagelinkhere}</IMAGE_URL3>
         <IMAGE_URL4>{imagelinkhere}</IMAGE_URL4>
        </Vehicle>';

$parsed = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

If you know, that the image url tags will always contain the name `IMAGE_URL`, you can check them:

```
foreach ($parsed as $key => $image) {
    if (strpos($key, 'IMAGE_URL') !== false) {
        echo $image, '</br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya clean, but only wrong because if the description is set it will return the description as an image

Comment: Then give a full example on how it would look like

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the nodes with Xpath.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<Vehicle>
 <TITLE>Some car name i dont need</TITLE>
 <DESCRIPTION>Some description i also dont need</DESCRIPTION>
 <IMAGE_URL1>image1</IMAGE_URL1>
 <IMAGE_URL2>image2</IMAGE_URL2>
 <IMAGE_URL3>image3</IMAGE_URL3>
 <IMAGE_URL4>image4</IMAGE_URL4>
</Vehicle>
XML;

$vehicle = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach ($vehicle->xpath('*[starts-with(local-name(), "IMAGE_URL")]') as $imageUrl) {
  var_dump((string)$imageUrl);
}
```

Output:

```
string(6) "image1"
string(6) "image2"
string(6) "image3"
string(6) "image4"
```

`*` selects all element child nodes. `[]` is a condition. In this case a validation that the local name (tag name without any namespace prefix) starts with a specific string.

This looks not that much different in DOM. But you start at the document context.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/Vehicle/*[starts-with(local-name(), "IMAGE_URL")]') as $imageUrl) {
  var_dump($imageUrl->textContent);
}
```